# Drawing custom for a class?

Tags: java, android, graphics

I have a class that simulates a `2-input AND gate` and I want to be able to draw a custom graphic for it, that represents an `AND gate` like this one:

[image: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/digital_circuits/images/and_gate.jpg]

I also want the user to be able to put a custom input from my input class by an `onclick` event on the input lines from the `AND gate`, and label the output of it with a TextView to be either true or false something like: "Y = A.B is true"

```java
public class AND extends Gate {

    private Input A;
    private Input B;
    private Input Output;


    public AND() {}

    public AND(String nameA, boolean valA, String nameB, boolean valB) {

        super(nameA, valA, nameB, valB);
    }

    @Override
    public void takeInput(Input X, Input Y) {

        A = X;
        B = Y;
        Output = new Input(A.getName() + "." + B.getName(), Logic()); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean Logic() {return (A.getValue() && B.getValue());}

    @Override
    public Input GenerateOutput() {

        if(Output == null)
            Output = new Input(A.getName() + "." + B.getName(), Logic());

        return Output;
    }

    @Override
    public void SetInputsValues(boolean a, boolean b) {

        A.setValue(a);
        B.setValue(b);

        if(Output == null) 
               Output = new Input(A.getName() + "." + B.getName(), Logic()); 

        else
            Output.setValue(Logic());
    }

}
```

Underneath is the second class, used for inputs.

```java
public class Input {

    private String name;
    private boolean value;

    public Input(String name, boolean value) {

        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }


    public String getName() {return name;}
    public boolean getValue() {return value;}

    // sets the value of the input
    public void setValue(boolean newVal) {value = newVal;}

}
```

My problem is how can I make a custom drawable that represent the AND gate and
responded to the user input while also using a standard XML layout for my main activity where I can create a TextView that prints the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try creating constraint layout with few widgets? You can use drag and drop and tweak anchors visually. It may not be perfect but my first approachgenerated such layout. Don't try to understand where do these magic numbers come from. When you play and tweak with positioning most of them will become clear.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/and_gate" /> <!-- your image name from drawable folder -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/aValue"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="318dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/bValue"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="false"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/aValue" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="357dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="355dp"
        android:text="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]